# Star schema, surrogate keys

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

We have big and wide flat files with a telemetry data. They arrive every day.

I'm going to create **star schema** in ADLA DB that will be populated with data from these wide big files. (looks like ADLA DB gives a lot of features (opposite to raw ADLS): indexes, statisctics, compression, distribution management...)

To generate surrogate keys we can use either:

1. row_number
2. hashing

What about hashing? What functions we can use to implement it? (I'm thinking about C#)

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question. But thought it worth mentioning that with what your suggesting you'll need to deal with the fact that you can't currently UPDATE or DELETE in USQL from ADL tables. You'll probably need to look at partitions more in you want rerun-ability.

Comment: Yes, i understand it. I gonna use partitioning by Date for FactXXX tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would like to understand why you want to use a surrogate key.

The current U-SQL tables are designed for supporting batch queries where you know most of the expected queries ahead of time. So you design your distribution keys and schemes (hash, direct hash, range) and clustered indexes to optimize the most expensive jobs.

Having a surrogate key makes sense if you need to use direct hash to manage data skew for example, but otherwise it may add complexities to take advantage of partition/distribution eliminations.

As to implementing your own hash functions, C# has some built-in hash functions or you can write your own. Eg., the C# `Object.GetHashCode` Method.

Comment: We have a telemetry timeline data stored in CSV. These CSVs are wide (a lot of columns). They are expected to be large, but i can control the size of every within 1-4Gb (as ADLA engine expect). I wanna load these data incrementally to ADLA DB to use features like: partitions, distributions, compatible joins/aggregates, statisctics etc. Also these data are very redundant and wide (a lot of columns). It is imposible to create a single distribution schema for a flat wide table to achive joins/group by compatibility for all major queries. I want to decompose the flat structure to star schema.

Comment: In the case we will have some Fact-tables that will share some Dim-tables. These fact tables will not be so wide as source flat table and i will be able to choose proper distribution schema in an every concrete case. Also it should lead to decrease size of data set. Also these fact tables will consists almost all from integers instead of big strings (as we have in flat schema). It should give benefits for aggregations (or not? at least it was true for Azure DWH). To implement the star schema i need a way to generate surrogate keys for DimTables. I can use row_number or some kind of hashing.

Comment: It should not broke value distribution in comparsion with a source data. Because if we have in source flat table a column with values 'Biiiiig string 1', 'Biiiiig string 1', 'Biiiiig string 1', 'Biiiiig string 2', 'Biiiiig string 3', then they will be replaced by surrogate integers 1, 1, 1, 2, 3

Comment: It is what and why i gonna do. It will be awesome if you comment it. Tahnk you as always.

Comment: I think your approach makes sense. Make sure the cluster keys and distribution schemes are aligned and designed for the most common joins/queries. Let me know if you have more questions after you implement it.

Comment: i implemented it. it has given me these benefits: compression ratio 4.8 - 5 (source_size / star_sch_tables_size). the compression is specific to our source data redundancy. most of queries is executed 4-5 times faster in comparsion raw vs star schema; also i can align my table distributions to queries; and we will save money for space/iops/cpu. also i can emulate secondary indexes if it will be needed, i will create thin table with a only needed columns and index/distribute it properly and use the thin table instead of base source table... i'm integrating my scripts to the ADF pipeline :)

Comment: also i can do partial aggregations of fact tables data by integer keys then join results with needed dim tables and then aggregate completely the small partial result dataset by dim properties (that almost all big strings); (looks like the U-SQL optimizer somtimes can produce an execution plan with the same logic for star schema without any explicit query rewrite)